# Allegro compile error: undefined reference to "PathFindOnPathA@8"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, allegro5

I have set up Allegro 5.0.4 with MinGW 4.5.2 and I am using the GUN GCC compiler with Code::Blocks.

When I attempt to compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ALLEGRO_STATICLINK
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
     ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

     if(!al_init()){
          fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
          return -1;
     }

     display = al_create_display(640, 480);
     if(!display){
          fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
          return -1;
     }

     al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

     al_flip_display();

     al_rest(10.0);

     al_destroy_display(display);

     return 0;
}
```

I receive the following build error.

Build Messages:

```
C:\i\liballegro-5.0.4-static-mt-debug.a(wsystem.o)
 In function "al_win_safe_load_library":

d:\Libraries\build\allegro\src\allegro-5.0.x\allegro-5.0.x\src\win\wsystem.c
 629 undefined reference to "PathFindOnPathA@8"

=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this:

- http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/608101/928306#target

> When you static link, if you get an undefined reference, just Google the function name (PathFindOnPath) and look up the library it needs. In this case it is "Shlwapi.lib".
>
> Or, I suppose it's libshlwapi.a on MinGW.

That is: add that library to your list of linked libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I could have swore I had all the libraries included and in the right order, guess I missed one. I checked the list like 5 times atleast.

Comment: That dependency is new to 5.0.4.